# What are the key bindings relevant to week-genda view?

Tags: key-bindings, org-agenda

Reminder: one enters the week-agenda view by typing `C-c a a`. Only serendipitously did I find out that `!` toggles "deadline inclusion". How would I find the description of similar key bindings from within Emacs, pertinent to this view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same way you do in most buffers:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> to call `describe-mode`

The vast majority of modes will list their keymap as part of that help.

In cases where that doesn't show you what you wanted to see, you can call the more general `describe-bindings` via <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> to list *all* active bindings for the buffer.  This includes the global map, and translation maps, so it's quite verbose.

In both cases you can use page navigation commands to skip between keymaps: <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> for `forward-page` and `backward-page` respectively (and <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>n</kbd><kbd>p</kbd> to `narrow-to-page`).